# FCM Push notification is not opening the application

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload

I am receiving FCM Push notifications but the app is not opened while taping the notification that are delivered in the system tray while the application is in the background.

My **Payload** from Back End looks like this:

```
Array(
    [registration_ids] => Array
        ([0] => some value)

    [priority] => high
    [notification] => Array
        (
            [body] => Booking Cancelled: Your recent Booking attempt for Sound mix was declined.
            [title] => Booking Rejected
            [click_action] => USER_BOOKING_REJECTED
            [sound] => default
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [type] => USER_BOOKING_REJECTED
            [booking_id] => 331
        )
)
```

I added this **USER_BOOKING_REJECTED** as action in Manifest for the concerned Activity.

Like this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".view.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="USER_BOOKING_APPROVED" />
                <action android:name="USER_BOOKING_REJECTED" />
                <action android:name="USER_BOOKING_AUTO_REJECTED" />
                <action android:name="USER_CANCEL_BOOKING" />
                <action android:name="USER_BOOKING_REMINDER" />
                <action android:name="USER_INVOICE_EDIT" />
                <action android:name="USER_INVOICE_NEW" />
                <action android:name="USER_INVOICE_REFUND" />
                <action android:name="USER_INVOICE_REMOVE" />
                <action android:name="NEW_MESSAGE" />
                <action android:name="SP_BOOKING_REMINDER" />
                <action android:name="SP_BOOKING_NEW" />
                <action android:name="SP_BOOKING_CANCEL" />
                <action android:name="SP_INVOICE_PAYMENT" />
                <action android:name="SP_NO_FUTURE_SLOT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="@string/host"
                    android:pathPrefix="@string/home_path"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Even though I get the notification in the system tray, the app is not opened while taping the notification. Any Help?

Comment: And where your notification click code?

Comment: This should open the HomeActivity right?

Comment: I dun know, but I don't find problem with your manifest.xml code

Comment: click_action should open the application in my understanding. Waiting for someone who knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make separate `<intent-filter>`s for separate `<action>`s in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Try to add just this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="USER_BOOKING_REJECTED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Added a single separate intent filter for actions and added the category default inside it. And it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data in payload from back end instead of notification.And then call firebase message service.

```
 const payload = {
                      data: {
                              /*set reuired data over here which you want for generating notification like below*/
                              message :  `${messageSnapshot}`,
                              vibrate :  '1',
                              sound :  '1',
                              largeIcon :  'large_icon',
                              smallIcon :  'small_icon'
                          }
                      };
                       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload).then(response => {
                                                                              // For each message check if there was an error.
                                                                              const tokensToRemove = [];
                                                                              response.results.forEach((result, index) => {

                                                                              const error = result.error;

                                                                              if (error) {
                                                                              console.error('Failure sending notification to', deviceToken, error);

                                                                              // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.

                                                                              if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                                                                              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                                                                                  tokensToRemove.push(deviceToken);
                                                                                  }
                                                                              }
                                                                        });
                                                                     });


<service
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>



public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static String TAG = "MessagingService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.e("MyFirebase","vcdjvbdbv");

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;


    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {


        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String message = data.get("message");}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. The another answer from @Anton helped me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had to upgrade the library for it to finally work.
Been scratching my head for 2 whole days lol.
Happy coding everyone!

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
```